# Classroom Assistant Will Not Expand Horizontally With Magnification

Tags: palettes

Being of advanced age I need magnification of tool bars, symbols etc.  I get this for all palettes except Classroom Assistant.  If I set a magnification that occurs but there is no horizontal increase of the palette size---so if what you need is on the right you are out of luck.  Or is it just my installation, whihc is version 11?

Robert Carroll

Comment: I can't reproduce this in version 11.1 on Mac OS, when I set the magnification in the lower right corner of the Classroom Assistant palette, the palette's vertical and horizontal size both increase.  What OS and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.0 on Windows 10

Comment: Also works fine in version 11.3 under macOs 10.13.4.